# CSS + Android + millimeters

Tags: android, css

anyone knows how can I get that a css millimeter (mm) look like a real mm in android?
On my PC it works ok.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean?? pls make your qtn clearer i have a strange feeling this qtn is going to close else

Comment: @droidhot he means that on android browser all proportions is smaller than on desktop. As it seems to me

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set `viewport` meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

All proportion is smaller in mobile browsers cause those by default recalculate all desktop dimensions so that desktop sites can fit to the small mobile screen